# Prime finder code

Tags: c, primes

It's saying the program has stopped working as soon as I put an input and press enter.Can't seem to find the reason though.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int m,f,count,i;
    m = 2;
    count = 0;
    while(m>=2){
        f = 0;
        for(i=0; i*i<m; i++){
            if(m%i==0){
                f = 1;
            }
        }
        if (f==0){
            count++;
        }
        if (count==n){
            printf("%d", m);
            break;
        }
        m++;
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the error message say?

Comment: It's saying the program has stopped working as soon as I put an input and press enter.

Comment: so its running...? but you said not  `not compiling`? how is that.?

Comment: Sorry I misspoken I'm fixing that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(i=0; i*i<m; i++){
    if(m%i==0){
```

`i` starts as `0`, so in `m % i`, you are dividing a number by zero.

Answer (score 0):

```c
m = 2;
// ...
while(m>=2){
    // ...
    m++;
}
```

`while(m>=2)` is useless isn't it? BTW did you heard of [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)?

Comment: I'm only practising C for a month. So,I don't know how else I could make an infinity loop.

Comment: It's simple `while(1){...}` or `for(;;){...}`. You can use also `do{...}while(1)`.

Comment: I understand, It would require using dynamically allocated array which is may be too soon for your C skill.